# Print out the task on which a host has failed at the end of a playbook?

Tags: ansible

I am running the deployment concurrently on a number of hosts. As can be expected, the output moves quickly during runtime and it is hard to track at what state each task ends. When I get to the end of the playbook I can see which host have failed which is great. However, I need to scroll through pages and pages of output in order to find out on which task did a certain host fail.

Is there a way to have a print out at the end of the playbook saying for example: 
"Host 1 failed on Task 1/cmd"

Comment: Check out if the actionable plugin(shows only failed events) in Callback Plugins helps: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/plugins/callback/actionable.html.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this fits your issue exactly, but you can help yourself with a little exception handling like this:

```
---

- hosts: localhost
  any_errors_fatal: true
  tasks:
    - block:
      - name: "Fail a command"
        shell: |
          rm someNonExistentFile
      rescue:
        - debug:
            msg: "{{ ansible_failed_result }}"
        #- fail:
        #    msg: "Playbook run failed. Aborting..."
        # uncomment this failed section to actually fail a deployment after writing the error message
```

The variable `ansible_failed_result` contains something like this:

```
TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": "rm someNonExistentFile\n",
        "delta": "0:00:00.036509",
        "end": "2019-10-31 12:06:09.579806",
        "failed": true,
        "invocation": {
            "module_args": {
                "_raw_params": "rm someNonExistentFile\n",
                "_uses_shell": true,
                "argv": null,
                "chdir": null,
                "creates": null,
                "executable": null,
                "removes": null,
                "stdin": null,
                "stdin_add_newline": true,
                "strip_empty_ends": true,
                "warn": true
            }
        },
        "msg": "non-zero return code",
        "rc": 1,
        "start": "2019-10-31 12:06:09.543297",
        "stderr": "rm: cannot remove ‘someNonExistentFile’: No such file or directory",
        "stderr_lines": [
            "rm: cannot remove ‘someNonExistentFile’: No such file or directory"
        ],
        "stdout": "",
        "stdout_lines": [],
        "warnings": [
            "Consider using the file module with state=absent rather than running 'rm'.  If you need to use command because file is insufficient you can add 'warn: false' to this command task or set 'command_warnings=False' in ansible.cfg to get rid of this message."
        ]
    }
}
```

I mostly use `stderr` when applicable. Otherwise I use `"{{ ansible_failed_result | to_nice_json }}"`.

hth